# How to plot shaded area in matplotlib with exchanging x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot an area plot, the function i am using is `stackplot`. The problem is, I wanna my x-axis to be the data, and y-axis to be the no. sample, in other word, exchange x and y axis. But, when i simply exchange, `ERROR: ValueError: Input passed into argument "'y2'"is not 1-dimensional.`. So, how can I exchange axis, if not possible with `stackplot`

```
# Basic stacked area chart.
pal = ["#9b59b6", "#e74c3c"]
x  = np.linspace(0, 50, num=50)
y1 = np.squeeze(np.random.rand(50,1))
y2 = np.squeeze(np.random.rand(50,1))
y  = [ y1 , y2]
plt.stackplot(x, y, labels=['A','B'], colors=pal, alpha=0.4)
"What I want"
#plt.stackplot(y, x, labels=['A','B'], colors=pal, alpha=0.4)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`plt.fill_betweenx`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx.html) to make a similar plot. The y-values need to be accumulated to draw each area. Line width can be set to zero (`lw=0`) in case you don't want a line to show the curve. The minimum x limit can be set to zero to avoid a gap between 0 and the plot.

Here is some example code comparing the standard `stackplot` and the version using `fill_betweenx`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pal = ["#9b59b6", "#e74c3c"]
x = np.linspace(0, 50, num=50)
y1 = 1+np.random.uniform(-0.2, 0.21, x.size).cumsum()
y2 = 1+np.random.uniform(-0.3, 0.31, x.size).cumsum()
y = [y1, y2]
labels = ['A', 'B']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))

axs[0].stackplot(x, y, labels=labels, colors=pal, alpha=0.4)
axs[0].legend(loc='upper left')
axs[0].invert_yaxis()

yi_cum = 0
for yi, color, label in zip(y, pal, labels):
    axs[1].fill_betweenx(x, yi_cum, yi_cum + yi, color=color, label=label, alpha=0.4, lw=0)
    yi_cum += yi
axs[1].legend(loc='upper left')
axs[1].set_xlim(xmin=0)
axs[1].invert_xaxis()

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation of Matplotlib, you need to enter "x" parameter as 1d array.

On your case, x equals 1d array and even when you convert y to the array (because it is in list form) it equals 2d arrar (50,2).  That's why it is working correctly on your first case;

```
plt.stackplot(x, y, labels=['A','B'], colors=pal, alpha=0.4)
```

And when you change it as following;

```
plt.stackplot(y, x, labels=['A','B'], colors=pal, alpha=0.4)
```

it will give you an error because first item (y) must be 1d array.

As a result, I suggest you to convert "y" parameter to 1d. Because first parameter of stackplot must be 1d array not 2d array. (it is 2d array in the case what you want)

**x:** 1d array of dimension N

**y:** 2d array (dimension MxN), or sequence of 1d arrays (each dimension 1xN)

You can see details here https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot.html

Comment: Thanks, @JohanC proposed a another solution, it is working.